# Result wasn't printing, why is `print` ignored after `return`?

Tags: python, printing

I'm working through the beginner's Python course in CodeAcademy. This is part of one of the exercises, where you're "checking out" at a grocery store, but I wanted to the code to print the final bill/"total" rather than just returning "total". I don't understand why it's not printing. I have tried putting it at the end, after the iteration, and, as here, within the recursion to see if it'll print after each step. When I run this code, nothing displays.

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}      
prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}    
food = shopping_list

def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        if stock[item]>0:
            total += prices[item]
            stock[item] -=1
    return total
    print total
compute_bill(food)
```

Thankyou - so I now understand that everything is ignored after `return total` - a better question might be **why is this?**
Is there a situation where you would include `print total` after `return total` in this way and *not* wish both to happen?

Comment: `return` ends a function *there and then*. `print total` is never reached.

Comment: Where are you actually *calling* `compute_bill()`? Why not print the return value *there*?

Comment: You need to move your `print` statement _before_ your `return` statement, and then call your function `compute_bill()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there a dupe (for me) for why anything under `return` on the same level of indentation is completely ignored? I've always been curious as to why this happens and you don't get an indentation error but no idea what to search, or why it shouldn't be caught.

Comment: @roganjosh: why would there need to be an indentation error? It's not a syntax error, it is a programming error. Python simply is not going to do flow analysis to detect if statements are unreachable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But at the same time, I wouldn't expect necessarily that it would be completely ignored by the interpreter. It's not an `if` condition that doesn't hold `True` and if I misalign is by one space it would be caught as an indentation error. If it cannot be interpreted, why is it not an indentation error?

Comment: @roganjosh Because if the `return` wasn't there the code would be perfectly executable. IndentationError is a subclass of SyntaxError. There is no syntax error here.

Comment: I've tried it with print total instead of return, same blank result, alse tried it at various indentations (ie inside and outside of the function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your approach, as it is well structured and the flow of the program is clear. However, you have not quite the right syntax for calling functions. With your current layout you need to do like this:

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

#food = shopping_list # Not needed as it is used as input parameter

def compute_bill(food):
    global stock # Not strictly needed, see below.
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        if stock[item]>0:
            total += prices[item]
            stock[item] -=1
    return total

print compute_bill(shopping_list) # Calling function and printing result
```

One other thing that may bite you in the future is that generally it is not possible to update a global variable `stock` within a function, because for most variables it is only a copy that is available for the function and that copy is not writable, if it is not in the input parameter list - unless the keyword `global`is used. However, for dictionaries (and lists and other collections) the `global` keyword is not needed.